# Is there an example of an opaque solution which can be made transparent by adding another solute, such that no chemical reaction occurs?

Tags: solutions

I am further interested in knowing exactly what the requirements are for a liquid to be transparent.

Comment: Welcome to chemistry.SE! If you had any questions about the policies of our community, you can ‎visit [the help center](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help) or take a ‎‎[tour](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) of the website.‎ I think this question may be flagged as too broad or primarily opinion based.

Comment: really? I thought it was quite specific. I am just looking for one example of a solution which is impermeable to a wavelength of light, such that when you add another solute (which does not react with any of the other solutes) becomes transparent to that wavelength.

Comment: I'm leaving it to see how it plays out. The example part **may be** and only **may be**, primarily opinion based. And the "too broad" part could be when you ask for why something is transparent. You can add a "reference-request" to avoid that part. Ah well, I think I'm being too nitpicky in here. It must be a symptom of the cold I caught. :)

Comment: When I "dissolved" phsophatidylcholine in water it was cloudy, because it made micelles. When I added triton X-100, a surfactant, it became transparent, which I assume because of smaller micelles. Not a chemical reaction, just a change of state I think.